# jquery multiselect dropdown selected values

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to javascript and jquery. I'm trying to create a multi-select dropdown list with "Select All" button. I finally find this nice plugin:
    http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

I followed the docs, and the dropdown is shown on the page. But I have trouble get the selected items.

**Here is what I did ( in javascript file controller):**

```
$scope.testSelectValues = $('#ms').multipleSelect('getSelects', 'text'));
```

and in html file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Month</label>
    <select id="ms" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#ms').change(function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
        }).multipleSelect({
            width: '100%'
        });
    });
</script>
```

This does not work. I don't get any testSelectValues with the proper selected values. Anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: Can you put the code in fiddler?

Comment: Can you post little more code of exact element and initialization bcos whatever you have tried seems good!

Answer (score 0):

Ok your question doesn't make much sense but I think I know what your trying to do.

Name your select menu `name=whatever[]` add the brackets after!! This will put all the selected values into an array.

To get the selected values - `var values = $('whatever[]').val();
For(i=0;i<values.length;i++) console.log(values[i])`

Excuse me if this is wrong, I'm on my phone and I know that it's something similar to that! When I get on my laptop I'll double check for you!

Comment: @user2528576 when I get on my laptop I'll check for you!!

Comment: I actually have tried this, but it don't work. $scope.values is still not defined.

Comment: You need to name your select menu. Name[] with brackets after it!